# New line only if not already at the beginning of the line

Tags: line-breaking

I have a command that puts two minipages next to each other depending on a percentual width argument for the left box (see MWE). Now I want to adjust the command such that it stays the same if it's already at the beginning of a new line and starts at a new line otherwise. There is probably a simple answer but I have not found a solution yet. Can you help me?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}

\providecommand{\partialpages}[3]{%
\pgfmathparse{.98-#1}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{#1\linewidth}%
    \vspace{0pt}%
    #2%
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\pgfmathresult\linewidth}%
    \vspace{0pt}%
    #3%
\end{minipage}%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\partialpages{.6}{left part}{right part}
\begin{ex}
\partialpages{.6}{left part}{right part}
\end{ex}
\end{document}
```

[image]